# Phalcon bulk insert performance. Models or Raw SQL

Tags: php, performance, insert, bulk, phalcon

Is there a way to do bulk inserts in phalcon php?

I tried inserting 10000 records using `\Phalcon\Mvc\Model create` and also the same using raw SQL: `insert into 'tablename' (a, b, c) values (), (), (), ... ()`

I set up this very simple test, and was surprised by the results

- using \Phalcon\Mvc\Model took around 36 seconds
- using raw sql took 3,6 seconds.

\Phalcon\Mvc\Model:

```
$transactionManager = new TransactionManager(); 

$transaction = $transactionManager->get();

$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setTransaction($transaction);
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++){
    $entity->setValue1(rand(1,50));
    $entity->setValue2(rand(1,50));
    $entity->setValue3(rand(1,50));
}
$entity->create();
$transaction->commit();
```

Raw SQL:

```
$query = "insert into 'tablename' (a, b, c) values ";

for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++){
    $values .= "(" . rand(1,50) . ", " . rand(1, 50). ", " . rand(1, 50). "),";
}

$values = substr($values, 0, strlen($values) - 1);
$query .= $values;
$this->db->query($query);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phalcon\Mvc\Model is slow because it creates a PHQL statement for every INSERT, then parses it and translates into the SQL dialect supported by the current DBMS. PHQL parsing is what makes this slow.

If you need performance, you will have to generate the INSERT statement yourself.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I was surprised that a framework that aims to be the fastest php Framework doesn't provide a way to do bulk inserts/update/etc. I also understand that one can always generate the insert statement manually. Still I was looking for the possibility of  using Phalcon Models to do bulk inserts.

Comment: Bulk INSERTs are not supported by all DBMSes supported by Phalcon (SQLite, for example)

Answer (score 5):

A Phalcon user created a library for this issue,
check it out [here](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1697/batch-insert) .